# Linear regression in R between two data frames

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have two data frames, one with predictor information and one with response data. Both matrices have row names expressing the same sample IDs in the same order (i.e. "TCGA_5896," "TCGA_5133"...)

To give you an idea of the format, the predictor matrix is of the form:

```
           NM_001010909_461 NM_002769_507 NM_005228_864 NM_001039703_3717 ...
TCGA_5896              0/0           0/1           0/0               0/0
TCGA_5133              0/0           0/0           0/0               1/0
```

And the response matrix of the form:

```
           X1007_s_at X160020_at  X179_at X200004_at X200005_at X200008_s_at ...
TCGA_5896   12.20168   5.705052  4.945441   12.13968   9.004182     9.113377
TCGA_5133   11.11169   4.885993  5.523197   11.64979  10.705409     8.680666
```

How can I do a simple pairwise linear regression between the two matrices and ensure the regression matrix takes all pairs into account? [I want to be sure that the same information for the same sample ID are being regressed together]

Comment: Just so that we are clear, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I expect the output matrix to be:

x(j), y(i), regression_coefficient, t-statistic, p-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reshape those matrices into "long" data.frame format so that each "sample" is on its own row like this:

id factor1 factor2 ... factorN response

then you can use lm(response~factor1+factor2+...+factorN, data)